# Dynamic Jquery UI Dialog Not Working In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

I've written a function that dynamically creates Jquery UI dialogs that looks like this.

```
/* +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   * dialogConstructor()
   * ++++++++++++++++++
   * 
   * Description:
   * 
   * This function will create a dialog based on the parameters you feed it
   * This is nice because it keeps you from having to create a new dialog for every situation
   * An example id construct would be "upload-excel" - which just allows this function to make unique id's.
   * 
   * +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   */
  function dialogConstructor(name,idConstruct,paragraph) {
      // First step: grab the HTML inside the generic dialog container  
      var genericDialog = $("#dialog-generic-container").html();

      // Make the id of the dialog unique
      var newDialog = genericDialog.replace('id="dialog-generic"','id="dialog-' + idConstruct + '"');

      // Also store that value
      var dialogId = 'dialog-' + idConstruct;

      // Change the Title
      newDialog = newDialog.replace('title="Basic dialog"','title="' + name + '"');

      // Change the id of the paragraph
      newDialog = newDialog.replace('id="dialog-p"','id="dialog-p-' + idConstruct + '"');

      // Change the content of the paragraph with the incoming info
      newDialog = newDialog.replace('Default Paragraph',paragraph);

      // Append to the html
      $("#outermost-id").append(newDialog);

      // Construct
      $("#" + dialogId).dialog({
          // Settings for the dialog
          autoOpen: true,
          buttons: {
              Ok: function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

The way the function works is by appending a new ID a new title and a new header onto the dialog then I append to the outer HTML itself. 
The only HTML I need to make this work.

```
<div id="dialog-generic-container" style="display:none"> <!-- Generic Dialog Container -->
    <div id="dialog-generic" title="Basic dialog">
        <div class="dialog-p-container">
            <p id="dialog-p">Default Paragraph</p>          
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Close Generic Dialog Container -->
```

Works in Google Chrome and Firefox but **NOT** IE (tested on IE 10).

Comment: please Provide fiddle link

Comment: Press F12 and post console errors.